# UART Serial comm. stopped working on raspberry pi3 using python3?

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, raspberry-pi3, uart, serial-communication

I have come across a problem on raspberry pi3, I was using UART serial comm perfectly, but I don't know what happened it is not working now, using the same script which I was using earlier. This time the scripts is not responding anything.

I make this UART comm working by configuring serial comm to /dev/ttyAMA0 and make Bluetooth working as well, everything was working fine, but suddenly it is not working.

The scripts I am using are:

Sender script::

```
import serial
from time import sleep
ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600)    #Open port with baud rate
while True:
    data = b'data to be send'
    ser.write(data)
```

Recever script::

```
import serial
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600)    #Open port with baud rate
while True:
    received_data = ser.read()              #read serial port
    sleep(0.03)
    data_left = ser.inWaiting()             #check for remaining byte
    received_data += ser.read(data_left)
    print (received_data)                   #print received data
```

Please help me resolve this...

```
# dmesg | grep tty

[    0.000000] Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1824 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=984 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=PARTUUID=9e90e4f3-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline 
fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
[    0.000283] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.732898] 3f201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 87, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    0.732962] console [ttyAMA0] enabled
[    0.734618] 3f215040.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x0 (irq = 166, base_baud = 31250000) is a 16550
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83209/blank-terminal-in-pi0-uart-connection) could help?

Comment: @not2qubit, Thanks for sharing, But didn't able to find something from that..

Comment: Reboot and try again, and check `dmesg` for clues.

Comment: @not2qubit, tried -- dmesg | grep tty

Comment: What makes you think software is the problem? "Not working" is not a problem description. Are the serial lines dead or does it send data at all?

Comment: You can do the simple loopback test by shorting the tx or rx in your serial device and see what you typing is echoed on your terminal?

Comment: @not2qubit, Tried the same image with another raspberry-pi, that worked, I think the Rx pin is broken, thanks for bringing this up

Comment: @ danglingpointer, yeah i tried the same loopback by sorting the Rx and Tx

Comment: @lundin, thanks for bringing this up, i think the Rx pin is damaged, what can be the reason for this??

Comment: If the actual port is broken, you have done something wildly harmful to it. Have you measured the signal at the physical pin with a scope and it looks ok there?

Comment: @Lundin, new to embed and pi and I don't even have scope...:(